# Glassfish and Spring setup tutorials/examples?

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

A simple web search didn't really turn up any examples... so I'm wondering if anyone could point me to any information on configuring Spring on Glassfish?  Everything I've been finding is horribly outdated.

Thanks!

Comment: what exactly you mean by Spring Glassfish setup. can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

Download Netbeans 6.8 it will give you glassfish and spring configured by default.

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/68/

Answer (score 0):

Configuring Spring is not really related to the fact that you are using GlassFish or Tomcat or whatever, you just configure it for an application that you then deploy on a server.

If you have a specific GlassFish related issue, you should probably clarify the question.